# project downloaded from github does not compile, missing libraries, android

Tags: android

Can anyone explain me how to overpass these problems?

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
Project 'DomoHome' is missing required library: '\Users\mattialipreri\dev\lib\json-lib-2.3-jdk13.jar'   DomoHome        Build path  Build Path Problem
The container 'Android Dependencies' references non existing library 'C:\Users\Ignacio\Desktop\Νέος φάκελος\cyrilmottier-GreenDroid-5f92227\GreenDroid\bin\com_cyrilmottier_android_greendroid.jar' DomoHome        Build path  Build Path Problem
```

I have downloaded a project from Github and I continue seeing a punctionmark next to project.

I have downloaded the GreenDroid library from github and pasted it to my Desktop, and then imported as a unique project to eclipse and then added it to the libraries of my project (I see next to it a green check).

Where to find the json-lib-2.3-jdk13.jar' file? I found some code in the web but I don't know. Must I create the file? And save it where? My user ath is not the one mentioned aboved? Where to changed it?

Comment: File an issue on the GitHub repository, asking the developer to supply documentation for where to obtain this JAR.

Comment: Click on the Issues link from any Web page in the GitHub repository.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the json-lib package [here.](http://json-lib.sourceforge.net/)

As for the greendroid path, I would check in the eclipse project properties. Under "Java Build Path" there is a tab "Libraries" with an item called "Android Dependencies." Expand this header and you should see some items including `annotations.jar` and one for the greendroid.jar item. It is pointing at the wrong path (possibly the path for one of the project developers?) - simply tell it where the jar you downloaded is (select "Android Dependencies" and click "Add JARs...") and it should work.

Answer (score 4):

Even though If you get the jar file but not the Library project and **if** the Library projects Contains the Layouts file then The .JAR file won't be help full;

Please read the README file from the GITHUB;

OR

search the jar file within ur project directory might be possible that it is available in some folder which uploader has inserted, or you can goto the JAVA Build path and select if it is available and it is not checked...